# как из View передавать данные в контроллер

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Я хочу записать checkbox'ы в разные строки таблицы, но не понимаю как из View передать несколько checkbox'ов как разные записи.  При этом без ActionResult где через ссылку передаются параметры.

Контроллер:

```
      [HttpGet]
      public ActionResult Form()
      {
        IEnumerable<Source> sources = db.Source;
        ViewBag.Sources = sources;

        return View();
       }

    [HttpPost]
    public void Form(Filtres filtres)
    {
        db.Filtres.Add(filtres);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

здесь я передаю из таблицы во вью данные что мне нужны, в методе post сохраняю.

View:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    @foreach (var k in ViewBag.Sources)
{
    <p><input type="checkbox" value="@ViewBag.SourceID" name="SourceID" /> @k.Name </p>


}
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="">Сохранить</button>
</div>
```

Проблема в том что, что SourceID пустой в таблице, хотя я думал что через name я передаю столбец что мне нужен, а entity framework понимает что мне нужно и делает все за меня.

контекст Source:

```
 public partial class Source
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(150)]
    public string URL { get; set; }

    [StringLength(150)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Teg { get; set; }
}
```

контекст Filtres

```
public partial class Filtres
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int? StudentID { get; set; }

    public int? SourceID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `@ViewBag.SourceID` - откуда берется?

Comment: db.Source покажите структуру класса

Comment: @Konst обновил вопрос

Comment: @Igor из таблицы, контекст обновил в вопросе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<p><input type="checkbox" value="@k.id" name="SourceID" /> @k.Name </p>
```

Comment: @k.id только нужно ТС

Comment: так как в foreach ViewBag.Sources, а я пытыюсь SourceID отобразить из другой таблицы, вылетает ошибка "модель не содержит определения для SourceID"

Comment: @Konst да, теперь записывается, но только один checkbox, а если я выберу несколько, то запишется только первый

Comment: public void Form(Filtres filtres) помедитируйте над этим. вы один экземпляр передаёте. хотите колекцию , то переделывайте свой код

Comment: @Konst Хорошо, спасибо, главный вопрос уже решен